# How come Mini Batch K means partial_fit method be useful for stream clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, scikit-learn, k-means, online-algorithms

Currently, I'm studying the **advance in cluster analysis regarding *stream clustering***. I ended up assessing **Mini batch K means** because of some comments I read on the Internet, like the following one:

> Many **clustering algorithms** can be **tweaked to be suitable for stream clustering**. I don't know of many implementations in scikit-learn that do it out of the box other than MiniBatchKMeans and Birch, which both have a **partial_fit method** allowing you to **stream data through in incremental updates.**

I'm familiar with online-offline stream clustering algorithms that use micro clusters to sum up the information, processing every element of the data set once.

Now, regarding the quotation, how come the `partial_fit` method be useful for streams? Or 'stream simulation' with time series data, at least. It seemed to me after reading [this example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dict_face_patches.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-dict-face-patches-py), that the whole MiniBatchKMeans procedure of selecting random batches in different iterations is done every time you call `partial_fit`, and I do not understand:

- how the final labeling is done; I mean, how can you get the final label for each element, having called `partial_fit` with many subsets of elements? **For me, you can only get the final centroids at the end, doing `mbk.cluster_centers_`.**
- how is it useful for streams? IMHO I think every element may be processed more than once, if it is randomly taken to be part of a batch in more than one iteration for a given `partial_fit` call.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In stream clustering you assume cluster centers move over time.

You aren't much interested in the "final" location (because the stream never ends), but only in their *current* locations.

If you use Mini Batch K-Means on a stream, you'd feed each batch of points from the stream into Mini Batch K-Means *once*, as if it were a new random sample. You don't repeatedly process data, but you assume the stream had enough samples to provide redundancy.